# How do you impose a time limit for input in ncurses when using getstr?

Tags: c, ncurses

Suppose I would like to limit the amount of time a user has to enter text when using the getstr function in ncurses.  How would I achieve this?

Comment: I would guess the [`timeout`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timeout) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this site](http://math.hws.edu/orr/s04/cpsc225/curses.html):

> **timeout(milliseconds)** ---   By default, if you call getch(), it will wait forever for the user to press a key. If you call timeout(0) before calling getch(), it won't wait at all -- if the user has already typed a character, it will be returned; if not, the predefined constant ERR will be returned instead. If you specify a positive value for the parameter to timeout(), then getch() will be willing to wait that many milliseconds before returning. For example, if you say timeout(1000) and then call getch(), it will wait up to one second. If the user has typed a character by that time, it will be returned; otherwise, the return value will be ERR. You can call timeout(-1) to reset getch() to its default behavior, waiting forever. You can use timeout() to write an event-driven program that does some kind of animation continually, but still responds when the user presses a key. The main() function would typical look something like: